# aioboto3 uploads failing with multiple errors

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, async-await, python-asyncio

Need help with aioboto3. Multiple errors during upload.

I am a newbie in the async world and am trying to upload multiple files from my laptop to S3 using aioboto3. Here is my code (most of it).
Just needed something quick and dirty to get multiple files from my local machine to AWS S3.
So I kind of copied [from here](https://aioboto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#)

Right now, not even sure whether using aioboto3 was a good idea, however, I really like the concept of async programming and any help/pointer to resolve/debug these errors will be greatly appreciated.

```
async def upload(staging_path):
    session = aioboto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
    v_file_path = Path(staging_path)
    blob_s3_key = bucket_folder + staging_path.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1]
    async with session.client("s3") as s3:
        try:
            with v_file_path.open("rb") as spfp:
                print(f"Uploading {blob_s3_key} to s3")
                await s3.upload_fileobj(spfp, bucket, blob_s3_key)
                print(f"Finished Uploading {blob_s3_key} to s3")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unable to s3 upload {staging_path} to {blob_s3_key}: {e} ({type(e)})")
            return ""


async def run_proc(file_upload_list):
    tasks0 = []
    for i in file_upload_list:
        task0 = asyncio.ensure_future(upload(i))
        tasks0.append(task0)

    v_ret = await asyncio.gather(*tasks0)
```

I am getting these errors for most of the files. only 3 -4 files out of all are getting uploaded to S3:

Error #1:

> [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (<class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError'>)

Error #2:

> Cannot connect to host my-s3-bucket-nm.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 ssl:default [getaddrinfo failed] (<class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError'>)

Error #3:

> Cannot connect to host my-s3-bucket-nm.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('XX.XXX.XXX.XX', 443)] (<class 'aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError'>)

Error #4:

> An error occurred (RequestTimeout) when calling the UploadPart operation (reached max retries: 4): Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed. (<class 'botocore.exceptions.ClientError'>)

Error #5:

> An error occurred (RequestTimeout) when calling the UploadPart operation (reached max retries: 4): Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed. (<class 'botocore.exceptions.ClientError'>)

Answer (score 2):

At this point I would say that this issue is partially closed.
About 90% solved.

Here are the 2 findings that I have:

1. Logging out of company VPN improved the code performance significantly.
2. aioboto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY) must also be provided with "aws region" parameter.

Since this issue is not solved 100% yet, I have switched my approach to good old multi threading. However, with the 2 steps mentioned above, code is running just fine with occasional network related aborts.

Thanks!